# Stacking attributes in a text field

Tags: arcgis-10.0, field-calculator

I am trying to stack my text in an attribute table using the field calculator, but it does not seem to be working.

My field name is: `Facilities`.
My attributes are in this format: `Public Access\Campground`

I want the field to read like this:

```
Public Access
Campground
```

So I am using this expression to stack the text:

```
Replace( [Facilities] ,"\",vbnewline)
```

But when I run it, it doesn't do anything. Can anyone steer me in the right direction?

Comment: `"\"` looks like a typo for `"\\"`.

Answer (score 1):

If you edit the attribute field and put the cursor in the field, with it between access and Campground.
Hit ctrl + enter.
That is hold the control button and hit the enter button at the same time.
That will place a line break in your data.

If you have the mapplex extension it will work with 10.0

Another option with 10.1 is use mapplex to stack labels. (it is included in arcgis desktop)
[image: stacklabels]

Comment: I know that trick works in excel, but on fortunately it does not work in ArcMap attribute tables. Thanks anyway.

Comment: The maplex solution would work if I was using the attributes for labels. but the purpose of the field I am trying to populate is for addinng information to a point pop-up in a flex app i am working on.

Comment: I use it all the time in arcmap labeling. I haven't used it in excel.

Comment: @cb3 you should go to your question and edit with that information.

Answer (score 0):

Found my problem. There were some extra points in my dataset, that had `null` values in the `Facilities` field. When I field calculated I included the nulls and the expression did not work. I tried to field calculate a selection of just the points that had text in the `Facilities` field and it worked fine.